# Как восстановить сontext после смены ориентации?

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Имеется ViewPager с FragmentPagerAdapter.
При смене ориентации произвожу сохранения, но приложение падает. т.к в Fragment приходит contex == null.

```
class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ArrayList<String> url;
Context c;
TextView txt;

public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> url, Context c, TextView txt) {
    super(fm);
    this.url = url;
    this.c = c;
    this.txt = txt;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return BlankFragment.newInstance(url.get(position), c, url.size(), position, txt);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return url.size();
}
```

и

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


String url;
Context c;
int size;
int position;
TextView txt;

public static BlankFragment newInstance(String url, Context c, int size, int position, TextView txt) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    fragment.url = url;
    fragment.c = c;
    fragment.size = size;
    fragment.position = position;
    //fragment.txt = txt;
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (c == null) {
        Log.e("load","--!!!--2");
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagepage);
    TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    txt.setText((position + 1)+"/"+size);
    txt.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
            (c.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-N.ttf"));
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(c));
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.openspace)
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options);
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: А зачем вы Context передаете в конструктор? В фрагменте Context можно получить методами `getActivity`, `inglater.getContext`, `container.getContext`

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish , это действительно работает, но открывается белый экран, где position и size = 0. Если полистать ,то где-то картинки открываются

Comment: А как у вас при size = 0 вообще что то листается?

Comment: @ SorryForMyEnglish В FragmentPageAdapter size != 0, но он нулевой уже в BlankFragment -> onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас неправильно реализуется `newInstance`. Должно быть так:

   ```
   private static final String ARG_URL = "url";
   private static final String ARG_SIZE = "size";
   private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

   public static BlankFragment newInstance(String url, int size, int position) {
       BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putString(ARG_URL, url);
       args.putInt(ARG_SIZE, size);
       args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
       fragment.setArguments(args);
       return fragment;
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
     int size = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SIZE);
     txt.setText((position + 1)+"/"+size);
   }
   ```

   При повороте устройства фрагмент пересоздается пустым конструктором и передачей бандла аргументов. Таким образом, все данные, которые вы передаете в фрагмент необходимо записывать в аргументы.
2. Передавать контекст в фрагмент не нужно. В фрагменте есть метод `getActivity()`, этого достаточно для получения контекста.
3. В случае, если уничтожение фрагмента даже на микросекундное время недопустимо (например, у вас там медиаплеер играет) можно воспользоваться `setRetainInstance(true);` в `onCreate` фрагмента, в этом случае фрагмент не будет уничтожаться при повороте устройства. Фрагмент будет отсоединен от активности (detached) и присоединен к вновь созданной активности при повороте.